# Jquery Tooltip .position on form items not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, positioning

My tooltips dont seem to be working correctly, I have made a small fiddle and tried out all other options but cant seem to get it to work, the form itself has around 50 form fields but I have only added 4 onto the fiddle.

I would like the tooltips to align to the right of the form field and not mess up when re entering the form field.

http://jsfiddle.net/H2fWS/

Please help out if you know how :)

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
    jQuery(".information").hide();
    jQuery("#info_starttip").show();
    jQuery(".textbox").focus(function(){
        jQuery(".information").hide();
        var getid = this.id;
        jQuery("#info_"+getid).position({
            of: this,
            my: "right top",
            at: "right top",
            collision: "fit"
        }).show();      
    });
});
```

Comment: are you allowed to change the HTML ?

Comment: where do you want the tooltips to show up? because right top of right top would put them on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/H2fWS/3/

```
jQuery(".information").hide();
        var getid = this.id;
        jQuery("#info_" + getid).show().position({
            of: this,
            my: "left top",
            at: "right top",
            collision: "fit"
        });
    });
});
```

I put `show()` before `position()` and changed it to position it's `left top` at the `right top` of the input.

Also, in your jsfiddle you had a comma after your last `position()` property, but i notice you don't have it in your post. That could cause problems in some browsers if it exists in your actual code.